# Call a function when new node link is created

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor

Is there any way to trigger a function call when a node link is created with another node? The called function should be able to access both the input and output nodes of the link created.

It would be helpful if possible in the *Materials* node tree and not the *Compositor* node tree.

Comment: AFAIK such a hook doesn't exist. What is the bigger picture, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Actually, I wanted to run a function when image texture node is updated (linked) with some other node. The function would check the link and change the values of the current image texture node

Comment: But to what purpose?

Comment: Like checking if input is Color type or not and then changing color space of image texture node automatically to non color data or color

Comment: This would be easier to implement as a cleanup pass after you've created the node tree. Just have a Python script go over all the connections and perform this cleanup.

Comment: Hey @AkashHamirwasia while Sybren might be right that you should do it at the end, there IS a way: The update-function of a node.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are writing your own nodes:**
Yes! You can add an update-function wich can handle input-tests.
Your update-function will be called on every change of the node, so on linking/unlinking it will be called. Here is how:

```
class MyNode(bpy.types.Node):
    bl_idname='MyNode'
    bl_label ='MyNode'
    # your update function must only take self
    def update(self):
        # your code here
        for skt in self.inputs:
            if skt.links:
                print("Input socket {} is linked".format(skt.name))
```

**If you are using existent nodes:**
No, probably not. You simply can not overwrite the nodes own update-functions.
They seem to be like a read-only-property returning a function to you.
Setting them wont work, no matter what.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I know that it is possible in Custom nodes but thought if it would be possible in default nodes. Probably not at this point in time.

Comment: @AkashHamirwasia Yeah, sorry. I tried a LOT of things, doing really really nasty hacks, but solely from within python, I was not able to change the behaviour. I guess you could fix something up with cpython, but that would probably be way more hassle than it's worth. But perhaps you'd like to write a driver for this instead? Should be possible... Well, best luck and stuff. :-)

Comment: @AkashHamirwasia Hey, I just thought: one could add a handler on redraw, and have it compare the nodetree.links to their previous state. (You could even just brute through it). Test if the from_socket.node is of type x, if the to_socket.node is of type y and then if from_socket.node.image is of the correct colourspace. If all but the last match, update the colorspace. As a redraw happens on each linking of sockets, it should work just like an updatehook...